How to build for older Android SDK version?
I have an older Android app, which I need to test. It has this preference in the config.xml
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />

Now, I've installed:

Gradle 6.9
Java JDK 8

java -version returns:
java -version
java version "1.8.0_411"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_411-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.411-b09, mixed mode)

I removed all Android SDK stuff from Android Studio which has an API level > 29.
When I ask cordova requirements, I get this:
legacy-app on  main [$!] ➜ cordova requirements
android-targetSdkVersion should be greater than or equal to 34.

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Please install the Android SDK Platform "platforms;android-34"
Gradle: installed /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gradle@6/6.9.4/bin/gradle
Some of requirements check failed

But why is Cordova asking for version 34? I want to build a legacy version and the build process should use the legacy jdk and gradle version and also the legacy android sdk.
Can someone guide what I need to do here? Thanks!

You need to target API Level 34 in order to publish to the Play Store, and if you are using the latest version of Cordova and cordova-android. To support older SDK's, set the minSdkVersion in your config as well
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="29" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="34" />

